# Assumptions needed for consistency of plug-in estimator

Tags: convergence, estimators, consistency

Assume $X,Z$ are random variables and let $x_0$ be a fixed number. I want to estimate $A =\mathbb{E}_{X,Z}[\frac{X}{P(X=x_0|Z)}]$.
If $P(X=x_0|Z=z)$ is known for all $z$ we can apply the LLN and derive a consistent estimator of $A$ given by
\begin{equation}\label{estimator}
\hat{A}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum \frac{x_i}{P(X=x_0|Z=z_i)}
\end{equation}
If $P(X=x_0|Z=z)$ is unknown we also want to estimate it via $\hat{P}_n$. What assumptions do we need on $\hat{P}_n$ such that $\hat{A}_n$ is still consistent if we plug $\hat{P}_n$ into $\hat{A}_n$?
Is it sufficient if $\hat{P}_n$ is also consistent?

Answer (score 0):

Consistency is not sufficient: suppose $\hat P$ is much too small with small probability -- eg $\hat P=2^{-n}$ with probability $1/n$.  $\hat P$ will still be consistent but $\hat A$ won't.

It's sufficient that $\hat P$ is consistent  and bounded away from zero (and bounded above, but that should be easy for a probability estimator)

Comment: Thanks! What is the formal argument that consistency of $\hat{P}_n$ is enough, when bounded away from zero and bounded above?